# How to get a Google Analytics ID that can be specified in Google Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-apps-marketplace

I looked at the following QA first, but it wasn't the answer I wanted.

- [How to set up Google Workspace Marketplace app listing event tracking in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463138/how-to-set-up-google-workspace-marketplace-app-listing-event-tracking-in-google)

I have published the add-on using Google MarketplaceSDK and it has passed the review and URL has been published. However, even in this situation, we still don't know how to issue Google Analytics IDs properly.

Specifically, I don't know what the website URL is that I need to specify when building the data stream settings in Google Analytics.

Q1. What are the Stream types for the released spreadsheet add-ons?

[image]

Q2. If I choose to stream the web, which URL is appropriate to specify?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following answers from a real application that I released

R1. Web

R2. Marketplace Listing URL

This URL will be published after the product has been released to Google Marketplace. It will be published in the following format

- `https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/{appname}/{Cloud Project Number}`

Answer (score 2):

R1: Stream Web.

R2: The URL entered in that field is not a determining factor for tracking, you can enter one at random if you don't have one.